# wirecloud IDE connect to fi-lab wirecloud instance error

Tags: eclipse, fiware-wirecloud

I am trying to connect to the fi-lab wirecloud instance through the wirecloud IDE plugin for eclipse. I follow the guide and i have created an application at the FI-Lab and tried the `https://mashup.lab.fi-ware.org/oauth2/default_redirect_uri` as the callback url.

When i try to authorize the connection, i get a redirect url mismatch.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need download a new version of the WireCloud IDE: the 4.3.2 version. This version adds support for KeyRock 2.0 (the software behind the [FIWARE Lab's Account portal](https://account.lab.fiware.org)). Then use `https://mashup.lab.fiware.org/oauth2/default_redirect_uri` (without a dash between `fi` and `ware`) as Callback URL :).

Comment: Is there an updated version of WireCloud IDE plugin? It seems the last version (4.3.2) is not working with recent versions of Wirecloud (config.xml templates are deprecated). Is there a way to connect directly to a Wirecloud server without PEP Proxy neither IDM? It would be quite useful to test widgets locally.